# how to rebase these complicated merged commits with git

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, rebase

Currently I have this complicated merged commits tree :

```
*   36cd4ff merge commit to rebase 12 (master,origin/master,HEAD)
|\  
| *   f8d22cf merge commit to rebase 11
| |\  
| | *   4381ba4 merge commit to rebase 10
| | |\  
| | | * c81227f commit to rebase 9
| * | | d16e5ca commit to rebase 8
* | | | c277df7 good 7
* | | | e712ceb good 6
|/ / /  
* | | 80e3baa good 5
* | | 1559030 good 4
|/ /  
* | e8bf45c good 3
* | 4ca2d92 good 2
|/
* d43f5ac good 1
```

I would like something like that (to rewrite clean history with a `git push --force`) :

```
* 36cd4ff merge commit to rebase 12
* f8d22cf merge commit to rebase 11
* 4381ba4 merge commit to rebase 10
* c81227f commit to rebase 9
* d16e5ca commit to rebase 8
|
* c277df7 good 7
* e712ceb good 6
* 80e3baa good 5
* 1559030 good 4
* e8bf45c good 3
* 4ca2d92 good 2
* d43f5ac good 1
```

If I do git rebase -i HEAD~6, only these commits appears :

```
pick 80e3baa good 5
pick e712ceb good 6
pick c277df7 good 7
pick d16e5ca commit to rebase 8
pick c81227f commit to rebase 9
pick 4381ba4 merge commit to rebase 10
```

where these commits have gone ?

```
* f8d22cf merge commit to rebase 11
* f8d22cf merge commit to rebase 11
```

The only 'solution' so far that has worked was to clone the repository and starting from
`c277df7 good 7`, copying files from source repo and doing a commit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you rebase, you solve all your merge-conflicts with the rebase.. so you dont need seperate merge-commits.. so first of all - revert all your merge-commits and then try the following:

until "good 7" you have a straight commit-line, after that you will have to put each commit on top of the tree (which has 7 as base)

put rebase 8 on top of rebase 7:

```
git rebase c277df7 d16e5ca
```

then put 9 on 8:

```
git rebase d16e5ca c81227f
```

solve all merge-conflicts along the way (you might have to do other commits or amend to your commit)

before you do anything, I suggest you do a backup of the repo by making a copy of the folder (you could rewind everything with git reflog, but sometimes a copy is just easier)

good luck

edit: if you dont want to lose the "merge-commits" then you can rebase the whole "merge-commit-branch" on top of commit 8 by doing rebase d16e5ca 36cd4ff (after the first rebase, of course)

Comment: How do you revert all merge-commit if it was not me who merged and pushed it to origin ? Do I have to create branch for each of it ?

Comment: Ok, it worked. For me it was easier (to understand) to create a branch for each merge-commits, `git branch _m1 36cd4ff`, and so one for 9, 10 and 11. Then `(master) git reset --hard c277df7` (good 7). And now it is easy to rebase each branch to master and merge it as --ff-only. Thanks, you show me the path.